# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion

Tags: java, android

I have this problem and I tried for looking the solution, can anyone help me please?

Message error is:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller
>   than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4]
>   C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-ui-0.4.4.aar\98e3098a92ea993df7efea933cd6b11e\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 14     Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,          or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 16,          or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)

And this my *build.gradle (app)* file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.koudyani"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' }
} }
 repositories {
        mavenCentral() }
 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.0.2'
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
// implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:16.0.5'
// FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
//mplementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:16.0.3'
// Required only if Facebook login support is required
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.38.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.2.1'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
// implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.hp.koudyani">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    //Facebook login
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges= "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter> </activity>
    //end facebook login
</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share you AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53468797/edit) to include the raw code and use the `{ }` button to format it correctly.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  As for the code as an image, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, increase your **minSdkVersion** to **16** in `build.gradle`.